# How should I write "Engine-X" correctly?

Tags: nginx

I've been studying **Engine-X** for a while and I don't understand why, there are places that I see *nginx* and sometimes *Nginx* or even *NGINX*, which one is the right?

Comment: I'm unsure if the question is on-topic or not but I doubt if re-asking on Server Fault will be appreciated. So please ignore the close notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer from a nginx developer [here](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,234083,234085#msg-234085). Message quoted below.

> We use all possible spellings. :)
>
> "nginx" when it's about software (http://nginx.org/en/) or command name
>
> "Nginx" when it's about company (Nginx, Inc.) (http://nginx.com)
>
> "NGINX" when it's about environment variable (http://nginx.org/r/env)